# How to display the date under the post title?

Tags: php, posts, functions, post-meta

He everyone i'm a newbie to wordpress/php and have 1 other problem. I am trying to get the date under the post title and not to display the category tags above the title. I tried it to change thing is the index.php but it would not work. How can I fix this for this page http://www.quintyvandijk.com/gallery/.

```
<?php
$edgt_blog_type = milieu_edge_get_archive_blog_list_layout();
milieu_edge_include_blog_helper_functions( 'lists', $edgt_blog_type );
$edgt_holder_params = milieu_edge_get_holder_params_blog();

get_header();
milieu_edge_get_title();
?>

<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['holder'] ); ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_after_container_open' ); ?>

    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['inner'] ); ?>">
        <?php milieu_edge_get_blog( $edgt_blog_type ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_before_container_close' ); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_blog_list_additional_tags' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: milieu_edge_get_archive_blog_list_layout();

milieu_edge_get_holder_params_blog();

show the content of these functions

Comment: This was in the archive.php

Comment: use $date_var = get_the_date('Y');  to get the date of post in variable and then echo out anywhere you want( e.g., echo $date_var; ) inside loop. get_the_date() function accepts some parameters.
for more info about parameters : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you, where should i insert this?

Comment: those functions I mentioned above may be in functions.php file of your theme.
you'll need to display date inside the function that displays your posts. Function that displays the post will have html markup as well.

Comment: I have looked but the functions above are not in the function.php I will include the function php underneath here.

Comment: you can search those functions with the help of text editor.

Comment: Yes i found milieu_edge_get_archive_blog_list_layout(); milieu_edge_get_holder_params_blog(); in archive and index. But what then because when i platse yout $date.. in my code it will not apper. Sorry for all the bother.

Answer (score 0):

This was in the archive.php

```
<?php
$edgt_blog_type = milieu_edge_get_archive_blog_list_layout();
milieu_edge_include_blog_helper_functions( 'lists', $edgt_blog_type );
$edgt_holder_params = milieu_edge_get_holder_params_blog();

get_header();
milieu_edge_get_title();
get_template_part( 'slider' );
?>

<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['holder'] ); ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_after_container_open' ); ?>

    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['inner'] ); ?>">
        <?php milieu_edge_get_blog( $edgt_blog_type ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_before_container_close' ); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_blog_list_additional_tags' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is piece of the function.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_theme_setup' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that adds various features to theme. Also defines image sizes that are used in a theme
     */
    function milieu_edge_theme_setup() {
        //add support for feed links
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        //add support for post formats
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'quote', 'video', 'audio' ) );

        //add theme support for post thumbnails
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        //add theme support for title tag
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        //add theme support for editor style
        add_editor_style( 'framework/admin/assets/css/editor-style.css' );

        //defined content width variable
        $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'milieu_edge_filter_set_content_width', 1100 );

        //define thumbnail sizes
        add_image_size( 'milieu_edge_image_size_square', 550, 550, true );
        add_image_size( 'milieu_edge_image_size_landscape', 1100, 550, true );
        add_image_size( 'milieu_edge_image_size_portrait', 550, 1100, true );
        add_image_size( 'milieu_edge_image_size_huge', 1100, 1100, true );

        load_theme_textdomain( 'milieu', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
    }

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'milieu_edge_theme_setup' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_is_responsive_on' ) ) {
    /**
     * Checks whether responsive mode is enabled in theme options
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_is_responsive_on() {
        return milieu_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'responsiveness' ) !== 'no';
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_rgba_color' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that generates rgba part of css color property
     *
     * @param $color string hex color
     * @param $transparency float transparency value between 0 and 1
     *
     * @return string generated rgba string
     */
    function milieu_edge_rgba_color( $color, $transparency ) {
        if ( $color !== '' && $transparency !== '' ) {
            $rgba_color = '';

            $rgb_color_array = milieu_edge_hex2rgb( $color );
            $rgba_color      .= 'rgba(' . implode( ', ', $rgb_color_array ) . ', ' . $transparency . ')';

            return $rgba_color;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_header_meta' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that echoes meta data if our seo is enabled
     */
    function milieu_edge_header_meta() { ?>

        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>"/>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
        <?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
            <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php }

    add_action( 'milieu_edge_action_header_meta', 'milieu_edge_header_meta' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_user_scalable_meta' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that outputs user scalable meta if responsiveness is turned on
     * Hooked to milieu_edge_action_header_meta action
     */
    function milieu_edge_user_scalable_meta() {
        //is responsiveness option is chosen?
        if ( milieu_edge_is_responsive_on() ) { ?>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200,user-scalable=yes">
        <?php }
    }

    add_action( 'milieu_edge_action_header_meta', 'milieu_edge_user_scalable_meta' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_smooth_page_transitions' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that outputs smooth page transitions html if smooth page transitions functionality is turned on
     * Hooked to milieu_edge_action_after_body_tag action
     */
    function milieu_edge_smooth_page_transitions() {
        $id = milieu_edge_get_page_id();

        if ( milieu_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'smooth_page_transitions', $id ) === 'yes' &&
             milieu_edge_get_meta_field_intersect( 'page_transition_preloader', $id ) === 'yes'
        ) { ?>
            <div class="edgt-smooth-transition-loader edgt-mimic-ajax">
                <div class="edgt-st-loader">
                    <div class="edgt-st-loader1">
                        <?php milieu_edge_loading_spinners(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }

    add_action( 'milieu_edge_action_after_body_tag', 'milieu_edge_smooth_page_transitions', 10 );
}

if (!function_exists('milieu_edge_back_to_top_button')) {
    /**
     * Function that outputs back to top button html if back to top functionality is turned on
     * Hooked to milieu_edge_action_after_header_area action
     */
    function milieu_edge_back_to_top_button() {
        if (milieu_edge_options()->getOptionValue('show_back_button') == 'yes') { ?>
            <a id='edgt-back-to-top' href='#'>
                <span class="edgt-icon-stack">
                     <?php milieu_edge_icon_collections()->getBackToTopIcon('font_awesome');?>
                </span>
            </a>
        <?php }
    }

    add_action('milieu_edge_action_after_header_area', 'milieu_edge_back_to_top_button', 10);
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_get_page_id' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that returns current page / post id.
     * Checks if current page is woocommerce page and returns that id if it is.
     * Checks if current page is any archive page (category, tag, date, author etc.) and returns -1 because that isn't
     * page that is created in WP admin.
     *
     * @return int
     *
     * @version 0.1
     *
     * @see milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed()
     * @see milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_shop()
     */
    function milieu_edge_get_page_id() {
        if ( milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed() && milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_shop() ) {
            return milieu_edge_get_woo_shop_page_id();
        }

        if ( milieu_edge_is_default_wp_template() ) {
            return - 1;
        }

        return get_queried_object_id();
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_get_multisite_blog_id' ) ) {
    /**
     * Check is multisite and return blog id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    function milieu_edge_get_multisite_blog_id() {
        if ( is_multisite() ) {
            return get_blog_details()->blog_id;
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_is_default_wp_template' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if current page archive page, search, 404 or default home blog page
     * @return bool
     *
     * @see is_archive()
     * @see is_search()
     * @see is_404()
     * @see is_front_page()
     * @see is_home()
     */
    function milieu_edge_is_default_wp_template() {
        return is_archive() || is_search() || is_404() || ( is_front_page() && is_home() );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_has_shortcode' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks whether shortcode exists on current page / post
     *
     * @param string shortcode to find
     * @param string content to check. If isn't passed current post content will be used
     *
     * @return bool whether content has shortcode or not
     */
    function milieu_edge_has_shortcode( $shortcode, $content = '' ) {
        $has_shortcode = false;

        if ( $shortcode ) {
            //if content variable isn't past
            if ( $content == '' ) {
                //take content from current post
                $page_id = milieu_edge_get_page_id();
                if ( ! empty( $page_id ) ) {
                    $current_post = get_post( $page_id );

                    if ( is_object( $current_post ) && property_exists( $current_post, 'post_content' ) ) {
                        $content = $current_post->post_content;
                    }
                }
            }

            //does content has shortcode added?
            if ( stripos( $content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {
                $has_shortcode = true;
            }
        }

        return $has_shortcode;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_get_unique_page_class' ) ) {
    /**
     * Returns unique page class based on post type and page id
     *
     * $params int $id is page id
     * $params bool $allowSingleProductOption
     * @return string
     */
    function milieu_edge_get_unique_page_class( $id, $allowSingleProductOption = false ) {
        $page_class = '';

        if ( milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed() && $allowSingleProductOption ) {

            if ( is_product() ) {
                $id = get_the_ID();
            }
        }

        if ( is_single() ) {
            $page_class = '.postid-' . $id;
        } elseif ( is_home() ) {
            $page_class .= '.home';
        } elseif ( is_archive() || $id === milieu_edge_get_woo_shop_page_id() ) {
            $page_class .= '.archive';
        } elseif ( is_search() ) {
            $page_class .= '.search';
        } elseif ( is_404() ) {
            $page_class .= '.error404';
        } else {
            $page_class .= '.page-id-' . $id;
        }

        return $page_class;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_page_custom_style' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that print custom page style
     */
    function milieu_edge_page_custom_style() {
        $style = apply_filters( 'milieu_edge_filter_add_page_custom_style', $style = '' );

        if ( $style !== '' ) {

            if ( milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed() && milieu_edge_load_woo_assets() ) {
                wp_add_inline_style( 'milieu-edge-style-handle-woo', $style );
            } else {
                wp_add_inline_style( 'milieu-edge-style-handle-modules', $style );
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'milieu_edge_page_custom_style' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_container_style' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that return container style
     */
    function milieu_edge_container_style( $style ) {
        $page_id      = milieu_edge_get_page_id();
        $class_prefix = milieu_edge_get_unique_page_class( $page_id, true );

        $container_selector = array(
            $class_prefix . ' .edgt-content .edgt-content-inner > .edgt-container',
            $class_prefix . ' .edgt-content .edgt-content-inner > .edgt-full-width'
        );

        $container_class       = array();
        $page_backgorund_color = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgt_page_background_color_meta', true );

        if ( $page_backgorund_color ) {
            $container_class['background-color'] = $page_backgorund_color;
        }

        $current_style = milieu_edge_dynamic_css( $container_selector, $container_class );
        $current_style = $current_style . $style;

        return $current_style;
    }

    add_filter( 'milieu_edge_filter_add_page_custom_style', 'milieu_edge_container_style' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_content_padding_top' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that return padding for content
     */
    function milieu_edge_content_padding_top( $style ) {
        $page_id      = milieu_edge_get_page_id();
        $class_prefix = milieu_edge_get_unique_page_class( $page_id, true );

        $current_style = '';

        $content_selector = array(
            $class_prefix . ' .edgt-content .edgt-content-inner > .edgt-container > .edgt-container-inner',
            $class_prefix . ' .edgt-content .edgt-content-inner > .edgt-full-width > .edgt-full-width-inner',
        );

        $content_class = array();

        $page_padding_top = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgt_page_content_top_padding', true );

        if ( $page_padding_top !== '' ) {
            if ( get_post_meta( $page_id, 'edgt_page_content_top_padding_mobile', true ) == 'yes' ) {
                $content_class['padding-top'] = milieu_edge_filter_px( $page_padding_top ) . 'px !important';
            } else {
                $content_class['padding-top'] = milieu_edge_filter_px( $page_padding_top ) . 'px';
            }
            $current_style .= milieu_edge_dynamic_css( $content_selector, $content_class );
        }

        $current_style = $current_style . $style;

        return $current_style;
    }

    add_filter( 'milieu_edge_filter_add_page_custom_style', 'milieu_edge_content_padding_top' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_print_custom_js' ) ) {
    /**
     * Prints out custom css from theme options
     */
    function milieu_edge_print_custom_js() {
        $custom_js = milieu_edge_options()->getOptionValue( 'custom_js' );

        if ( ! empty( $custom_js ) ) {
            wp_add_inline_script( 'milieu-edge-script-handle-modules', $custom_js );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'milieu_edge_print_custom_js' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_get_global_variables' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that generates global variables and put them in array so they could be used in the theme
     */
    function milieu_edge_get_global_variables() {
        $global_variables = array();

        $global_variables['edgtAddForAdminBar']      = is_admin_bar_showing() ? 32 : 0;
        $global_variables['edgtElementAppearAmount'] = - 100;
        $global_variables['edgtAjaxUrl']             = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

        $global_variables = apply_filters( 'milieu_edge_filter_js_global_variables', $global_variables );

        wp_localize_script( 'milieu-edge-script-handle-modules', 'edgtGlobalVars', array(
            'vars' => $global_variables
        ) );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'milieu_edge_get_global_variables' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_per_page_js_variables' ) ) {
    /**
     * Outputs global JS variable that holds page settings
     */
    function milieu_edge_per_page_js_variables() {
        $per_page_js_vars = apply_filters( 'milieu_edge_filter_per_page_js_vars', array() );

        wp_localize_script( 'milieu-edge-script-handle-modules', 'edgtPerPageVars', array(
            'vars' => $per_page_js_vars
        ) );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'milieu_edge_per_page_js_variables' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_content_elem_style_attr' ) ) {
    /**
     * Defines filter for adding custom styles to content HTML element
     */
    function milieu_edge_content_elem_style_attr() {
        $styles = apply_filters( 'milieu_edge_filter_content_elem_style_attr', array() );

        milieu_edge_inline_style( $styles );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_core_plugin_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if Edge Core plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_core_plugin_installed() {
        return defined( 'EDGE_CORE_VERSION' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if Woocommerce plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_is_woocommerce_installed() {
        return function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_visual_composer_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if Visual Composer plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_visual_composer_installed() {
        return class_exists( 'WPBakeryVisualComposerAbstract' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_revolution_slider_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if Revolution Slider plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_revolution_slider_installed() {
        return class_exists( 'RevSliderFront' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_contact_form_7_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if Contact Form 7 plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_contact_form_7_installed() {
        return defined( 'WPCF7_VERSION' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_is_wpml_installed' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function that checks if WPML plugin installed
     * @return bool
     */
    function milieu_edge_is_wpml_installed() {
        return defined( 'ICL_SITEPRESS_VERSION' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'milieu_edge_max_image_width_srcset' ) ) {
    /**
     * Set max width for srcset to 1920
     *
     * @return int
     */
    function milieu_edge_max_image_width_srcset() {
        return 1920;
    }

    add_filter( 'max_srcset_image_width', 'milieu_edge_max_image_width_srcset' );
}
```